# Get schema using SODA api and python

Tags: python, soda

I am using python to download a city's data. I want to get the schema with python (data types and names) for columns download with sodapy. I can get the data fine but is is all of type string. So, it would be nice to have data types so I could build a proper schema to load the data into.

On the website, they have data types laid out for the columns.
https://data.muni.org/Housing-and-Homelessness/CAMA-Property-Inventory-Residential-with-Details/r3di-nq2j

There is so metadata at this url but it does not have the column info.
https://data.muni.org/api/views/metadata/v1/r3di-nq2j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way but this url returns a json response with the information.

http://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?ids=r3di-nq2j

Answer (score 3):

Unable to comment due to low rep, so adding a new answer, in case anyone else comes across this in search results, as I did.

Omitting /metadata/v1/ from OPs original URL as such: https://data.muni.org/api/views/r3di-nq2j will return full table metadata.

Additionally, Socrata HTML response headers include special fields (X-SODA2-Fields and X-SODA2-Types) containing a list of the column names and data types returned in the results.

Ref: https://dev.socrata.com/docs/response-codes.html

Comment: Is the `/api/views/view-uuid` endpoint documented somewhere?